# 25% discount on selected products

Tags: magento-1.9

I am looking for a little help setting up a 25% discount on selected products. I would like it so that if a collection of products are added to the basket a 25% discount is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Promotions > catalog price rules > ADD New rule`

[image]

under conditions > select sku's that you want to give 25 %

**If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :**

[image]

under actions >

```
APPLY : By Percentage of the original Price & follow the below image
```

[image]

let me know if you get any problems, for more information follow : [link](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=L1IWV6f0MeeK8Qec-6DACA&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+catalog+price+rule)

Comment: I dont have By Percentage of the original Price  in the dropdown

Comment: this is default magento feature. can you cross check one more time ?

Comment: In actions I have:

percentage of product price discount
fixed amount discount
fixed amount discount whole cart 
buy x get y free

Comment: than now is everything is working fine ?

Comment: I have just realised I have this set up as a shopping cart rule. I will try your option now. Sorry

Comment: no worries :-) let me know once you done.

Comment: Just tried what you have and I have one of the products in my basket but its not showing any discount

Comment: it should show on view page only, can you try reindexing by system > index management .

Comment: Would it be possible to do it as  a Shopping Cart rule instead?

Comment: in that case you have to inform your customers to apply coupon code? is that okay?

Comment: check the updated answer with image. or if possible please show the screenshots that what you tried ?

Comment: Yes that would be okay I think, as long as you can add 1 of each product to the basket. and then apply a code and 25% discount is deducted

Comment: even there is an option to give discounts for particular category.  if you using `shopping cart price rule` than also you have to select for skus.

Comment: In conditions I gave **If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: SKU** I have all the SKU comma separated. Actions: Fixed Amount to whole cart: 25%

Comment: chnage `ALL` to `ANY` or can you try for only one sku

Comment: Changed it, so I have asked the client if they could check

Comment: is it working now ? 25 % is applying for products ?

Comment: Is it applying a discount, but I have asked the client to double check

Comment: this is nice :-) even you also try by placing an order and check in backend whether amount got discount or not. also did you set up cron jobs from server side ? otherwise catalog price rule may not work in magento after some time.

Comment: i didt understood, can you please explain ?

Comment: They would now like it as a bundle instead, so not a pricing rule.

Comment: than please post new question with clear requirements